# Using resolve to "select" a single object out of a list of object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to figure out the best way to "resolve" to a single object model given a list of objects based off of Angular UI's route path.

For example, I have a parent view state that is instaniated at `/users` which contains a list of Users. When I select a user, I want the child view to resolve the selected user. The child view's route is like `/users/:userId` and I want the child view to basically "wait" for the parent view to GET all the users, then proceed to instaniate the child controller and view with the user with the ID equal to `userId` in the `$stateParams`. I know this must be a typical use-case, but am unable to find any other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually quite easy to do, just use the previously resolved users object from your parent state and use that to resolve a new promise in your child state:

States:

```
$stateProvider.state('users', {
  'url': '/users',
  'controller': 'usersController',
  'templateUrl': 'users.html',
  'resolve': {
    'users': [
      '$http',
      function ($http) {
        return $http.get('users.json');
      }
    ]
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('user', {
  'parent': 'users',
  'url': '/:id',
  'controller': 'userController',
  'templateUrl': 'user.html',
  'resolve': {
    'user': [
      '$q',
      '$stateParams',
      'users',
      function ($q, $stateParams, users) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        users.data.forEach(function (user) {
          if ($stateParams.id == user.id) {
            deferred.resolve(user);
          }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Controllers:

```
angular.module('app').controller('usersController', [
  '$scope',
  'users',
  function ($scope, users) {
    $scope.users = users.data;
  }
]);

angular.module('app').controller('userController', [
  '$scope',
  'user',
  function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.user = user;
  }
]);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sKkLdnWkjdilsQ3IvU6i?p=preview

Comment: Ok so the trick is to just control the Users array via an Angular Service

Comment: In this case, for this example. i'm using the $http service directly in the resolve itself, normally one would encapsulate that into a service or use a resource or something like that. I did it this way to keep the example simple and not too confusing. Take a look at the resolve examples and then especially the `translations` and `translations2` resolve. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve